How can I mouse scroll zoom towards a selected object?
To clarify, I don't mean the " zoom towards mouse position " button in the preferences and I also don't mean " View > frame selected "
I mean to just scroll towards the currently selected 3D object. A bit like " zoom towards mouse position " in a way that the mouse is always at the center of the object.
How exactly can I do this? Is there a setting for that? To really just mouse scroll zoom towards the selected object?

Not sure that you can. I just hit the '.' (period) key on the numpad, but I'm not sure whay key combination you could use if you don't have a keyboard with a numpad.
